# How to build a table with some specifications

Tags: html, css, css-tables

Not really sure if that made complete sense, here is another try:

I'm trying to make a table where each row of alternating color has a border radius on either top sides of it, in such a way that the space(or background) created due to border radius is filled by the previous row color.
Here is the Css:

```
table {
  background-color: grey;
  border-radius
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px 10px 0px 0px; 
  border-radius: 10px 10px 0px 0px; 
  border-spacing: 0;
}

td,th{
  height:28px;
}

table th{
  background-color:blue;    
}

table tr th:first-child {
  border-radius: 10px 0px 0px 0px;
}

table tr th:last-child {
  border-radius: 0px 10px 0px 0px;
}

table tr td:first-child {
  width: 200px;
}

table tr td:first-child {
   width: 200px;
}

table tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/WOF6Nqu.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  padding-top:10px;
  margin-top:-10px;
}

table tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-image: url(" http://i.imgur.com/BLcmMtw.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

table td:nth-child(1),
table td:nth-child(2),
table th:nth-child(1),
table th:nth-child(2) {
  border-right: 2px solid white;
}
```

Comment: what have you tested ?

Comment: put the code/html you have done so far. We need to see some effort.

Comment: Well, put it in the question…

Comment: @feeela  Here is the JS link: https://jsfiddle.net/maazonline/e4eaoso8/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**(Works only in Firefox)**

Simply let the table cells have the important background-color, and let each row have the same color as the cells in the previous row:

https://jsfiddle.net/svArtist/20rhemuf/

(Some fixes are needed for your header, but it's not too bad

```
td:first-child, th:first-child {
    border-radius: 10px 0 0 0;
}
td:last-child, th:last-child {
    border-radius: 0 10px 0 0;
}
/* Now set the colors here */
table tr:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: #bbb;
}
table tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #ABDBEA;
}
table tr:nth-child(even) td {
    background-color: #bbb;
}
table tr:nth-child(odd) td {
    background-color: #ABDBEA;
}

/* fixes for the header, as it is different */
table tr:first-child {
    background-color: transparent;
}
table tr:nth-child(2) {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Comment: This still doesn't allow the the colour after the border-radius to be different for each row. I'm trying for somehthing like this: [link](http://imgur.com/R9snOAW)

Comment: I don't quite sure what it is you want... except for the colors, my JSFiddle does exactly that: One header color, then alternating colors for each row; each row looks like it's overlapping the previous one. What am I missing?

Comment: Not sure if you're using a different browser, I see this in chrome [link](http://i.imgur.com/oVZRqLl.png). I still can't figure how to color the top ends of each row with the background color of the row above it. For example in the screen shot I shared earlier, the orange row background overflows to the second row on either ends of it. I can't find any overlap in your code.

Comment: Oh no... It appears it only works in firefox right now... I see this: http://i.imgur.com/pYRYRif.jpg

BUT... I had created a different way anyway, this one should work in Chrome too: http://jsfiddle.net/svArtist/nrmqszkz/
Even though the question is on hold: This might solve your problem